# program closes when PyEval_CallObject is called

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

I am trying to use C module in python script, so when code reaches PyEval_Callobject call program crashes/closes.

C side code:

```
    static PyObject *register_inactivity_callback(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *temp;

    if (!PyTuple_Check(args) || PyTuple_Size(args) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input parameter\n");
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    }

    temp = PyTuple_GetItem(args, 0);
    if (!PyCallable_Check(temp))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "parameter must be callable\n");
        Py_RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    Py_XINCREF(temp);
    Py_XDECREF(inactivity_callback);
    inactivity_callback = temp;

    Py_RETURN_TRUE;
}

void inactivity_callback_internal(void *arg)
{
    PyObject *arglist;
    struct input_event *event = (struct input_event *)arg;

    if (inactivity_callback && event)
    {
        arglist = Py_BuildValue("()");
        PyEval_CallObject(inactivity_callback, arglist);
        Py_DECREF(arglist);
    }
}
```

Python side:

```
def on_inactivity():
    print 'inactivity'

register_inactivity_callback(on_inactivity)
```

I have tested this code on ubuntu desktop platform and its working, but when I have moved to ARM, program started to crash/close on PyEval_CallingObject.

Is there anything suspicious that I am doing in the code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't see anything obvious. Do the pointers look valid when you run it through a debugger and/or have you tried using valgrind or similar to check for memory corruption? A quick thing you could try is to temporarily remove the `Py_[X]DECREFs` and see if that prevents it from crashing, although you may end up leaking memory instead.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the root cause. PyEval_CallObject function need to be wrapped by PyGILState_Ensure/Release functions. See http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html (Non-Python created threads).

```
gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
PyEval_CallObject(inactivity_callback, arglist);
PyGILState_Release(gstate);
```